# Unicode Line and Paragraph Separator is Not Properly Supported

Tags: unicode, paragraphs, line-endings

Emacs is displaying Unicode `LINE SEPARATOR` and `PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR` (PS) as rectangle. PS also does not end a paragraph. How can I make emacs treat these characters properly?

Comment: What happens if you customize user option `paragraph-separate` to be a regexp string that matches just character PS? As its doc says, "(If you change this, you may have to change ‘paragraph-start’ also.)"

Comment: I have changed those but I dont know how to check whether it works. I have also changed `bidi-paragraph-separate-re` and `bidi-paragraph-start-re` to various values and it does work, except when I set it to unicode values (including PS).

Comment: For unicode values I tried with these patterns. `"^\2029"`, `"^\\2029"`, `"^∈"` and literal PS `"^<PS>"`. None of which seems to work.

Comment: If you want to specify non-ASCII characters in a regex, you need to either enter it literally or use one of the Unicode escape syntaxes, eg '\u2029'